# RavenDb Upgrade on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ravendb

I want to upgrade my RavenDb server instance and I am trying to follow the instructions here
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.3/csharp/start/installation/upgrading-to-new-version

I downloaded the package.
Then I copied my settings.json file to a backup folder but I don't see a .pfx or .pem file, because I have set RavenDB up in unsecure mode.
I stopped the RavenDb instance.
So do I go ahead and just unpack the package and let it overwrite? or delete the folder and unpack the ravendb file and copy back over the settings and data?
I'm a little hesitant on this procedure because I'm not familiar with Ubunutu server or linux.

Comment: So I just went ahead and unpacked the package and it seems everything is as it should be. I'm guessing the backup of the data and settings is a precautionary step in case of failure. edit...It would be nice if there was a little bit more help on this subject.

Comment: Upgrading can be a little bit scary the first time. But the instructions are straightforward. You just need to delete the old package binaries and replace them with the new package binaries. Among the binaries, there are couple of not binaries files like the database folder that include your data, the setting.json with all dedicated settings, and the certificate. You can always copy the whole server directory and you can practice on a dummy server. In addition, you can keep the data folder, the certificate, and the settings.json in a separate location. What additional help do you need?

Comment: To use settings.json in another location you need to add `-c={PATH_TO_SETTINGS}` (`dotnet Raven.Server.dll -c={PATH_TO_SETTINGS}`). To set data folder in another location set [`DataDir`](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/server/configuration/core-configuration#datadir). To set certificate in another location set [`Security.Certificate.Path`](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/server/configuration/security-configuration#security.certificate.path)

Comment: @IgalMerhavia Not so much more help needed but confirmation and clarity. Mostly for me it's the unfamiliarity with both linux and Ravendb. And thanks for the tip on changing the settings and data path I'm going to do this so when the next update arrives I'll be ready to go. Appreciate your effort and help.